# Scoreboard Merging Question

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to use a `/scoreboard` players operation in minecraft and I am trying to convert points from Level-1 (Team: Level-1 Player: Level-1) and I wan to give it to total (Team: Total Player: Total-Points) and it is giving me an error even though I have all of the objectives and teams. (Error Message: Selector '@a[team=Total]' found nothing)

Can someone tell me why this isn't working and maybe give a solution?

Comment: You need to provide us with the command you're attempting to use, otherwise we can't tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: Oh yes... I am using the command /scoreboard players objectives Level-1 Points += @a[team=Total] Points

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the individual scores, you can just use a repeating command block with a conditional chain command block after it with the repeating command block decreasing the score by 1 on players with a score > 0 (@a[score_SCORENAME_min=1) and the in the conditional command block have a command that increases the total score by 1. If you want to keep the original score, what you want to do is create a "dummy" score that increases whenever the other score does, then do the same as above.^^^

Comment: I got this command that I listed from another person on this forums (It was in their command format) but it worked when I tried it before it worked perfectly.